# setting env say config is undefined

Tags: angularjs

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').service('env', function env() {

        var _environments = {
            local: {
                host: 'localhost:3000',
                config: {
                    apiroot: 'http://localhost:9000'
                }
            },
            dev: {
                host: 'dev.com',
                config: {
                    apiroot: 'http://localhost:3000'
                }
            },
            test: {
                host: 'test.com',
                config: {
                    apiroot: 'http://localhost:3000'
                }
            },
            stage: {
                host: 'stage.com',
                config: {
                apiroot: 'staging'
                }
            },
            prod: {
                host: 'production.com',
                config: {
                    apiroot: 'production'
                }
            }
        },
        _environment;

        return {
            getEnvironment: function(){
                var host = window.location.host;
                if(_environment){
                    return _environment;
                }

                for(var environment in _environments){
                    if(typeof _environments[environment].host && _environments[environment].host == host){
                        _environment = environment;
                        return _environment;
                    }
                }

                return null;
            },
            get: function(property){
                return _environments[this.getEnvironment()].config[property];
            }
        }

    });

})();
```

Using this service but it says config is undefined on caling time env.get('apiroot')

Can you please suggest where i am wrong thanks a ton

//I wanted to set enviornemnt for stagging, local and production i try to use this custom service but getting error please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the host and api is not correct please use same for those

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').service('env', function env() {

        var _environments = {
            local: {
                host: 'localhost:9000',
                config: {
                    apiroot: 'http://localhost:9000'
                }
            },
            dev: {
                host: 'dev.com',
                config: {
                    apiroot: 'http://localhost:3000'
                }
            },
            test: {
                host: 'test.com',
                config: {
                    apiroot: 'http://localhost:3000'
                }
            },
            stage: {
                host: 'stage.com',
                config: {
                apiroot: 'staging'
                }
            },
            prod: {
                host: 'production.com',
                config: {
                    apiroot: 'production'
                }
            }
        },
        _environment;

        return {
            getEnvironment: function(){
                var host = window.location.host;
                if(_environment){
                    return _environment;
                }

                for(var environment in _environments){
                    if(typeof _environments[environment].host && _environments[environment].host == host){
                        _environment = environment;
                        return _environment;
                    }
                }

                return null;
            },
            get: function(property){
                return _environments[this.getEnvironment()].config[property];
            }
        }

    });

})();
```

Try this